# How to print all the lines associated to my sorted result in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk, extract

I have following command that takes a log, sorts it based on the $6 col and makes a unique process on that. At the end, I have just one column as a result.

```
zgrep 'send_sms_*' logs_new_2015-11.gz |zgrep '^2015-'| zgrep '+1' | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq
```

I need to see all the rest of the lines instead of the just one column after execution of all those commands and I don't know how I have to do it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Feel free to add more details to the question. Hint what is the content of the file `logs_new_2015-11.gz`, what is the output expected by you etc

Comment: Doe't matter the example of log. Awk is extracting just 1 col and I need after all these commands be able to see whole the line not only one command. and this is not related to an example of log. I just need to know how I can see whole the log instead of one col.

Comment: Why don't you try removing the `awk` part from the command?

Comment: I need to sort my log based on one col, that is the $6. That's why I need it.

Comment: `sort` command can take care of the sort on any column, check out `-k` option of `sort`

Comment: Doesn't `zgrep` do a grep on a zipped file and produce plain text output? If so then why are you executing 2 more zgreps on the non-zipped output of the first zgrep? Why are you using chains of greps before awk when awk can do everything useful that grep can do? Why are you calling sort and uniq separately when sort has a `-u[nique]` option?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, awk is extracting what you ask it to extract and it is losing the rest of the information, so the best way it keep s what we want to have in awk

```
zgrep 'txt_*' logs_new_2015-11.gz |zgrep '^2015-'| zgrep '+1' | awk '{print $6 " " $0}' | sort | uniq | awk '{$1="";print $0}'
```

At the end I am removing the first column and I am keeping the rest of the line.

Comment: I suggest you get a beginner shell programming book, e.g. Bash Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson, and the awk book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and read at least the first couple of chapters of each and then revisit this.

Answer (score 0):

1 awk is enough after a *unzip* (keeping first zgrep for this purpose)

```
zgrep 'send_sms_*' logs_new_2015-11.gz \
 |awk '/^2015-/&&/\+1/{u[$6]++}END{for(U in u)print U}'
```

add `| sort` for sorting if mandatory and basic akw

add `BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"}` as first action in awk action with gawk

Comment: This give the bash: syntax error near unexpected token `U' error.

Comment: To me this command  seems to be more complicated. My suggestion is to use the my comment above.

Comment: sorry, a `'` misstyped was in fact a `/`, corrected in post

Comment: @MaryaimPashmi  if a simple awk action is more complicated than 6 piped process including 2 basing awk instruction you are right but from a process point of view and maintenance, I don't agree